# Rails 6 session cookie gets too big

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session-cookies

I run into a problem with my Rails 6 app (deployed to production via docker) since today that the session cookie gets bigger and bigger and after about 4 or so page requests, it's so big that it triggers a CookieOverflow exception.

EDIT: I found the culprit by following what is going on in the session object (I simply added <%= session.inspect %> to the bottom of my layout): It's the [backpedal gem](https://github.com/Greyoxide/backpedal); it stores the "tree" of visited sites and of course at some point, this gets too much. Now I need to figure out how to work around this :)

Comment: This is a red herrring. Noty has nothing to do with the session storage or even cookies in general.

Comment: You're going to have to do a code audit and check if your application code or dependencies are doing anything foolish with the session. The usual culprit is that people stuff the entire oauth auth hash into the session or that you're passing huge objects into the flash.

Comment: So - I *think* it has to do with the flash notifications. I was trying to track this down a bit, and it seems the session cookie gets bigger every time a flash message is generated... there is no authentication in my app, so that cannot be the culprit - thanks max, I was reading about this too but unfortunately not the issue.

Comment: Yes, it could have something to do with the flash but unless you're doing something very wrong that code isn't even using the flash. It should be assumed that `form` is actually passed from the controller in the same request. It could also be something completely unrelatated like for example a bodged attempt at caching something in the session.

Comment: so you were absolutely right, whether or not I use Noty makes no difference. I am now trying to find the best way to track what is changing the session cookie. Any ideas highly appreciated :)

Comment: found the culprit. see edit above :)